# Compilar app para ios feitos no react em ambiente windows

Tags: android, ios, windows, react-native, osx

Estou estudando react native e preciso compilar um app para android e ios.
Gostaria de saber se posso desenvolver tudo no ambiente windows e depois só copiar os arquivos pra uma maquina virtual rodando OS X para compilar e publicar o app

Comment: Yep, aqui tem um tutorial mais explicado de como fazer [Xcode On Windows](https://blog.udemy.com/xcode-on-windows/)

Comment: @CaiqueCampos apesar de ser eficiente pra produção, é ilegal, e caso gerado com hackintosh e enviado para a loja, logo é detectado e a conta é banida

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode fazer isso sem problemas, mas sugiro que voce teste tudo em um iphone ou no simulador do mac antes, pois sempre tem uns detalhezinhos que não funcionanam ou funcionam um pouquinho diferente no ios.

Nao sei se voce usa iphone ou android mas uma coisa que vejo muito e uma pessoa desenvolver e testar somente no android e acabar esquecendo de alguns detalhes de usabilidade/interface um pouco mais caracteristicos do ios.

Por exemplo ja vi gente fazendo funcionalidades que acabavam ficando dependentes do botao voltar do android, por exemplo para fechar uma modal, o que deixa um usuario do ios "preso" na modal.